# how to sort array values in desending order based on numbers

Tags: array

Please help me to sort this values in dessending order

Iam getting related version in below array:

```
 for(var j=0;j<prodVersions.length;j++) {
                component.set("v.prodVersion",prodVersions[j]); 
   }
```

prodVersions[j]->VMWARE CENTER 4.1X,VMWARE CENTER 5.0X,VMWARE CENTER 5.1X,VMWARECENTERSERVER 6.0X,VMWARECENTERSERVER 5.5X

How to sort array values in desending order.shown in the image. But sorting should be done based on number present in the versions

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to extract the version number and do some subtraction:

```
prodVersions.sort(
    (a,b) => {
        let av = Number(a.match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0]), bv = Number(b.match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0]);
        return bv - av; // inverted subtraction to sort largest->smallest
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can sort your array in descending order as follows:

```
 prodVersions.sort();
 prodVersions.reverse();
```

The sort function sorts the array in ascending order and then the reverse function reverses the array so it is now in descending order. Below is a link if you'd like to learn more.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp

Comment: I updated questions..it's based on number present in versions